# LINQ Matching on Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query in an MVC application that allows users to search multiple fields at the same time for resident information.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish.

The user has 3 textboxes to search from:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Voters", FormMethod.Get))
{
<p>
    Last Name: @Html.TextBox("voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch", !String.IsNullOrEmpty(voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch) ? voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch : "")
    First Name: @Html.TextBox("voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch", !String.IsNullOrEmpty(voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch) ? voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch : "")
    Address:    @Html.TextBox("voterSearchModel.Address", !String.IsNullOrEmpty(voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch) ? voterSearchModel.AddressSearch : "")
</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Lets say we have the following in our table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|FirstName          | LastName               | Address        |
|Bob                | Doe                    | 123 Sesame St. |
|Joe                | Doe                    | 123 Sesame St. |
|Cookie             | Monster                | 111 FooBar Lane|
|Bob                | Magoo                  | 321 Street Ave.|
|Mark               | McAllister             | 213 Duckie Ave.|
|Joe                | Doe                    | 18 Sunset Blvd |
```

My LINQ query right now is as such:

```
voters = voters.Where(voter => (voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch != null && voter.Last_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch))
                                            || (voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch != null && voter.First_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch)
                                            || (voterSearchModel.AddressSearch != null && voter.StreetNameComplete.Contains(voterSearchModel.AddressSearch)));
```

Say the user searches for First Name: "Joe" Last Name: "Doe" to find all of the Joe Does in the city. The query, right now will return ALL the "Joe"s and ALL of the "Doe"s.

What would I need to do in order have it return only the "Joe Does"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing an overall *or* search `||`, it sounds like you want an *and* search `&&`. But your test for empty search strings is wrong - you want to say a record matches if (search string is null) OR (search string is a match).

```
voters = voters.Where(voter => (voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch == null || voter.Last_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch)) &&
                               (voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch == null || voter.First_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch)) &&
                               (voterSearchModel.AddressSearch == null || voter.StreetNameComplete.Contains(voterSearchModel.AddressSearch)));
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are `OR`-ing your search terms together when you really want to `AND` them.

Try building your query by conditionally applying separate `Where` clauses for each criteria:

```
if (voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch != null)
{
    voters = voters.Where(voter.First_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.FirstNameSearch));
}
if (voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch != null)
{
    voters = voters.Where(voter.Last_Name.Contains(voterSearchModel.LastNameSearch));
}
if (voterSearchModel.AddressSearch != null)
{
    voters = voters.Where(voter.StreetNameComplete.Contains(voterSearchModel.AddressSearch));
}
```

This should give you the results you want while also making the code a little easier to reason about.